# javascript, html and indexeddb

Tags: javascript

firstly, I created a form using html5, I can ordinarily retrieve the form inputs to display on the webpage but now I want to make use of indexeddb to store and retrieve data using javascript.
secondly, I could not locate where the database that I created using indexeddb is been stored.
here is the html code;

`<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
     <form>
        First name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <br>
        Last name:<br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="click to continue" >
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>`

Answer (score 1):

> I could not locate where the database that I created using indexeddb is been stored

It will be stored wherever your browser wants to store it. That's implementation detail of the browser. It isn't designed to be accessed other than from JavaScript on the domain that created it. You shouldn't need to know about the internal workings of the browser.

Comment: I need to know because I want to retrieve or rather see the information.

Comment: Use the same JavaScript API you used to set the data to retrieve it.